# jQuery onload replace specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var text = $(".name")
    return $(this).text().replace("â˜…", "  &#9733;");
});
```

This is what I have right now but doesn't seem to work idk why?

I used to have code that did work just only in chrome console.

```
$(".name").text(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace("â˜…", " &#9733;");
});
```

Comment: Try putting exactly what you have in your second snippet, inside your first part's document ready.  "It only works in the console" is suggestive of a timing issue, which document ready can help alleviate, depending upon the exact issue.

Comment: In your first block of code, $(this) corresponds to $(document), not $(".name"). Just put the code of the second block within the $(document).ready function.

Comment: I can’t put a function in a function can i ? Could you put what you mean in a codeblock?

Comment: Sure you can put functions in functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more what you're looking for:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".name").text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace("â˜…", "  &#9733;");
  });
});
```

Comment: still have the same issue only works in chrome console